# React/TypeScript: state in component array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, state

I have the following TypeScript code:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

interface FooProps {
    name: string
}

interface FooState {
    name: string
}

export class Foo extends React.Component<FooProps, FooState> {

    ITEMLIST = [];

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: this.props.name
        }
        this.initItemList();
    }

    initItemList() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            this.ITEMLIST.push(<li>{this.state.name}'s item number {i}</li>);
        }
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            name: event.target.value
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>{this.state.name} owns these items:</p>
                {this.ITEMLIST.length > 0 &&
                    <ul>{this.ITEMLIST}</ul>
                }
                <label>Name:
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
                </label>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render
    (<Foo name='john' />,document.getElementById('content'));
```

I want to achieve that the list elements I generated change as soon as I change the value of the input element, so I thought - keeping in mind my pass-by-reference-idea from a perfect world - that even after I put the list elements into the array, they should still change as soon as the state changes.

Guess what - they don't. So I guess, the value is simply being copied into the element. Of course it would be possible to re-fill the array, but that seems weird somehow.

Where am I going wrong? I am probably missing some very obvious React/TypeScript/JavaScript basics, but I've been banging my head against the wall and I'm too blind to see it.

Thanks in advance,

t.

Answer (score 0):

do you want `initItemList` to get called every time the state changes?

If that's the case, then add `componentWillUpdate` to your class and have it call `initItemList`

e.g.

```
componentWillUpdate() {
  this.initItemList();
}
```

Comment: No, this is exactly what I wanted to avoid. initItemList() would repopulate the list. And in real life, this would be React components instead of list elements, which would get re-instantiated. I was thinking that it would be way cheaper to put that state variable in there to avoid having to reinstantiation.

Comment: gotcha, if you're trying to avoid re-instantiation in the DOM you should create a react element type for these elements and just pass updated state as props - the same object instance will get used (i can make an example of this if you'd like)

Answer (score 0):

Aaron's answer brought me back on track. I now have two classes:
Foo.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react'
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import { ListElement } from './ListElement';

interface FooProps {
    name: string
}

interface FooState {
    name: string
}

export class Foo extends React.Component<FooProps, FooState> {

    ITEMLIST: string[] = [];

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: this.props.name
        }
        this.initItemList();
    }

    initItemList() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            this.ITEMLIST.push("'s item number " + i);
        }
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            name: event.target.value
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>{this.state.name} owns these items:</p>
                {this.ITEMLIST.map((val) =>
                    <ListElement name={this.state.name + val} />
                )}
                <label>Name:
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
                </label>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render
    (<Foo name='john' />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

and ListElement.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface ListElementProps {
    name: string
}

export class ListElement extends React.Component<ListElementProps, undefined> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <li>{this.props.name}</li>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

This way, the ListElements in the array do not get instantiated on every render and still reflect the current state.

Regards,

Thorsten